# Is it possible to retrieve data from an XML file through XSD in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, xsd, xml-parsing

Let's say I have an XML file that has all sorts of data in it (integers, strings...) and I also have the corresponding XSD.

Is it possible to extract the XML data (and perhaps display it in a `DataGridView`) by using only the XSD?

If so, how would one go about that?

Comment: xsd is only the schema (format) of the xml and not the data.  There are tools that automatically create class structures from the xsd so you can serialize/de-serialize the xml.  Or you can write your own code to parse the xml.

Comment: I see. So it isn't really possible. Got it, thanks. I'm going to look into serialization now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML file will have to be involved, of course, in order to access its data.  An XSD could *help* in accessing the data of an XML file in the following ways:

- An XSD can be used to automatically derive classes in a programming
  language (such as Java or C#) which will be able to read (unmarshal) the XML
  file into objects, allow programmatic access and manipulation, and
  write ([marshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science))) the objects back to XML.
- An XSD, combined with a validating parser, can be used to parse the
  XML file and provide the following:

  1. Access to values.
  2. Notification of violations of the constraints specified in the XSD

(Note that access without validation (#1) requires no XSD even.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so perfectly. This helps me a lot.